# How to find 2nd same word in a given string using python?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, python-multithreading

this is my example string: "x: 2 : x, z: 3 :z, w :4: w,x:22:x "
 my aim is to find NUMBERS between letter "X", I was able to find using the below code, but that only works for 1st occurrence or letter "X", how to do for 2nd occurrence, I am not getting how to use for loop?

```
        Start_strp = BGP.find('x')
        strp_BGP = BGP[Start_strp+len(content)+1:3]
        return "peer-address:" + strp_BGP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I will do it is using string methods **split** and **strip**. Those may be very useful: split breaks a string into a list based on a separator and strip removes the spaces around a string. I will use the **in operator** instead of find as for the case I will present we only need to check if the 'x' is present or not, and not its position.

I will also use the already built in functions **map** and **filter**, both apply a function to each element in a list. Filter will return only those elements for which the function returns True, and map will return the output of the function for each element in the list. The keyword **lambda** defines an anonymous function with the input and the output separated by a colon.

```
s = "x: 2 : x, z: 3 :z, w :4: w,x:22:x "

l = s.split(',')  # ['x: 2 : x', ' z: 3 :z', ' w :4: w', 'x:22:x ']
f = filter(lambda s: 'x' in s, l)  # ['x: 2 : x', 'x:22:x ']
map(lambda s: s.split(':')[1].strip(), f) 
['2', '22']
```

I encourage you to use those functions but I also understand it is important to master the for loop. Best!

Comment: Hello! thanks, the program works, but here is the issue...In my actual string the number to be fetched is not between ":" its given like this "x> 2342 <x", so how to modify the map function to handle this issue, and if possible can you explain me  s.split(':')[1]  in map function.

Comment: Happy to help! Then instead of using the string method split we can use the function split in the ***re module*** (it contains tools for regular expressions that can be very useful for your case). For that you have to first import the re module, and then you split the string by using re.split('>|<', s). Like in the previous case if for example s = 'x> 2 < x, it will break it into  ['x', ' 2 ', ' x'] and you just want the item in the index 1, that's why you use [1].

Comment: The code will be now  
    `import re  

    s = "x> 2 < x, z> 3 <z, w >4< w,x>22<x "  
    l = s.split(',')  
    f = filter(lambda s: 'x' in s, l)  
    map(lambda s: re.split('>|<', s)[1].strip(), f)`

Comment: i am getting output as NONE, actually my string is s = "axe>2<bxe" for simplification I wrote only "x" here. sorry, i didn't knew it will get so complicated. as I new to these functions, I am getting it slowly and so asking so much questions.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. When I do  
`import re`  
`s = "axe>2<bxe"`  
`re.split('>|<', s)[1].strip()`  
I get '2', what do you get?